# What is "The supported operations" means in TensorFlow Lite for Microcontrollers?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, openmv

I want to create an image classification model for facial recognition with a OpenMV Cam H7 and tensorflow. It's explained in the [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/microcontrollers/build_convert#operation_support) that "TensorFlow Lite for Microcontrollers currently supports a limited subset of TensorFlow operations, which impacts the model architectures that it is possible to run"

"The supported operations can be seen in the file [all_ops_resolver.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tflite-micro/blob/main/tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.cc)"

so what are supported operations?, and how do I know which supported operations I'm using in my model

Answer (score 0):

If you open the link to the all_ops_resolver.cc file you just shared you will be able to see the list of supported operations. The list includes the basic building blocks needed to design a facial recognition model, like the layers Conv2D/DepthwiseConv2D and FullyConnected, and activations as Relu and Softmax.

To see the layers being used in a model you can just call model.summary() in Tensorflow/Keras.

I recommend you to start by looking for a simple Tensorflow example showing how to build a face recognition model and try to build a similar one just using operations supported by Tensorflow-lite for Microcontrollers.